# How can I get a list showing the subtraction result between current Row ID and Previous Row's ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I get a list of IDs in MS SQL table with a number showing the difference between the current row's ID and the previous row's ID -assuming that I have 'ORDER BY ID DESC'

```
SELECT ID, ???? AS [CurrentID - PreviousID]
FROM foo
ORDER BY foo.ID DESC
```

Comment: can you provide a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ID,
  ID - coalesce(
                 (select max(ID) from foo foo2 where foo2.id<foo.id)
                , 0) as Diff
FROM foo
ORDER BY foo.ID DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f21eb/3

Answer (score 1):

Try following query using `CTE` and `row_number()`:

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f21eb/2)**

```
create table foo (id int)

insert into foo values 
(1),(5),(8),(9)

;with cte as (
   select Id, row_number() over (order by id desc) rn
   from foo
)
select c1.id, c1.id-c2.id as [currentId - previousId]
from cte c1 
      left join cte c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
order by c1.rn

| ID | CURRENTID - PREVIOUSID |
-------------------------------
|  9 |                      1 |
|  8 |                      3 |
|  5 |                      4 |
|  1 |                 (null) |
```

Comment: why the left join?  Why not "where rn > 1" instead?

Comment: @DanBracuk, Left join is used to select all the rows. To use `Where rn >1 ` as you suggested, min id always has to be 1 which is bit of hard coding. He can modify the query as it suits for the requirement.